# Is it required to declare all members in class constructor

Tags: javascript

Are the following two class declarations esentially the same?

```
class ColorSpectrum
{
    constructor(min, max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
        //this.Colors = []; edited
        this.Colors;
    }

    SetColors(colors)
    {
        this.Colors = colors;
    }
}
```

vs

```
class ColorSpectrum
{
    constructor(min, max)
    {
        this.Min = min;
        this.Max = max;
    }

    SetColors(colors)
    {
        this.Colors = colors;
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, in both cases `Colors` will be `undefined` if `SetColors` has not been called in an instace of `ColorSpectrum`.

In a wider sense, do I need to state explicitely all members of my class in the constructor or they can be defined "on the fly" in different members (such as `SetColors` in my example above)?

Comment: `If I understand correctly, in both cases Colors will be undefined if SetColors has not been called in an instace of ColorSpectrum.` No. In the first case its an empty array.

Comment: Oh, yes, correct. My bad

Comment: After your edit, the line `this.Colors;` doesn't declare a property. It accesses the `Colors` property, it doesn't exist. No problem, the expression is evaluated to undefined, and the execution continues. The object *still* doesn't have a `Colors` property, even one set to `undefined`.

Comment: *"do I need to state explicitely all members of my class in the constructor or they can be defined "on the fly" in different members"* An "instance" of a class is still an object. Properties can be added and removed from objects anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare all members in the constructor, but you do need to be prepared for undefined values if you don't. You're examples show this well because they are not the same:

```js
class ColorSpectrum_one {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.Min = min;
    this.Max = max;
    this.Colors = [];
  }

  SetColors(colors) {
    this.Colors = colors;
  }
}


class ColorSpectrum_two {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.Min = min;
    this.Max = max;
  }

  SetColors(colors) {
    this.Colors = colors;
  }
}

let c1 = new ColorSpectrum_one()
c1.Colors.push("some color") // no problem
console.log(c1.Colors)

let c2 = new ColorSpectrum_two()
try {
  c2.Colors.push("some color") // error undefined.
} catch (err) {
  console.log("error: ", err.message)
}
```

In this case, if you know `this.Colors` will be an array, it makes a lot of sense to declare it in the constructor. Without doing that it is essentially required that you call `SetColors` before using this class and if that's the case it should be part of the constructor.

Also, from a usability perspective, it's nice to be able to look at the constructor of a class and quickly see the expected properties.

Comment: Is there a preffered way? I mean, it is a good practice to initialize all my fields or it depends on my preferences? My main concerns are that if I have some instances of ColorSpectrum with SetColors called, and other without, are those two classes different? Sorry for the excessive wording. Coming from C++ and C#.

Comment: @Sturm classes are much more flexible and less strict in JS. All the class is really doing is setting up a chain of prototypes. Add properties to an instance doesn't change much in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand correctly, in both cases Colors will be undefined if SetColors has not been called in an instace of ColorSpectrum.

Let's check.

```js
class ColorSpectrum {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.Min = min;
    this.Max = max;
    this.Colors = [];
  }

  SetColors(colors) {
    this.Colors = colors;
  }
}

class ColorSpectrum2 {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.Min = min;
    this.Max = max;
  }

  SetColors(colors) {
    this.Colors = colors;
  }
}

const spectrum1 = new ColorSpectrum(0, 1);
const spectrum2 = new ColorSpectrum2(0, 1);

console.log(spectrum1.Colors);
console.log(spectrum2.Colors);
```

Nope.

BTW, it's a common convention to uppercase class names, but lowercase properties and methods. So: `class ColorSpectrum`, but `this.min`, `this.max`, `setColors`.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether a `ColorSpectrum` is valid when `Colors` has not been initialized.
In any language, when a constructor returns, the object should be in a valid, usable state. So whether the constructor needs to initialize all fields depends on exactly what constitutes a valid, usable state for a particular class.